# How does a UFO fly so fast?

Tags: flying-in-formation

Now, we have seen the UFOs by US Navy's onboard cameras, they are so fast and they do change their directions very quickly. How do they do so almost breaking the laws of physics?

Comment: Since the object is, by definition, "Unidentified", it's going to be difficult to detail how and why it is able to fly quickly and have such sudden direction changes. At best, this question will garner purely speculative answers (unless a member of the US Navy with intimate knowledge of the particular incident happens to stop by and be willing to share what has probably been deemed `Classified` or `Secret` information), and this particular slice of the web doesn't deal well with speculative answers. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] to see if you can bring your question in line...

Comment: ...with expected community standards. Additionally, it would be most helpful if you would [edit] your post to at least include a link to the video in question, as not all of "we" have seen said footage.

Comment: Since this forum is for fact based questions and answers about known and identifiable aviation subjects, it does not lend itself to conjectures or opinion based discussions. You might try the Sciencefictionstackexchange or the Physicsstackexchange for your answer.

Comment: If you want a real answer to your query, you might change it to read something like, “What design considerations would have to be taken into account to make an aircraft accelerate, decelerate, and/or change directions so quickly? And, how do we make such velocity changes survivable by pilots?”

Comment: An answer not based on opinion is possible, no need to close this.

Comment: I don't think speculation is on topic here and I fail to see how this question can be answered without speculating.

Comment: @Hobbes This is a fact-based site. UFO questions will be on topic when they are at least identified, and thus no longer can be called "unidentified flying objects".

Comment: @ZOMVID-20  have you read the link in my answer? The objects have been identified.

Answer (score 1):

This is about 3 videos released by the Pentagon. The vehicles in those videos don't fly extraordinarily fast. The [3 videos in question show normal aircraft and a balloon](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47488/are-these-ufos-on-the-videos-released-by-the-pentagon-still-unidentified). The reported speeds are incorrect due to imperfections in the equipment used and optical illusions.